# Crop text that overlap another text with different color

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, detection

[image][image][image][image]

How can I crop text that overlaps another text with a different color? I can not use inRange to remove the blue color because there are a lot of images with different lights and contrast. I can not use the const value inRange. How can I find the value to use in range or another way to crop the black font text. (filter, or another image processing method)

Not: All same type cards images. Numbers and 'Gozlu' are black fonts and the title's font is blue. Because of light(i guess) not barely recognizable.

Comment: If the text you want is always black and you can assume that no other text is black, then use inRange to threshold black. Or do it HSV where V is very low and S is very low.

Comment: Like blue color, the black color could not be filtered a const value for all images. Some black values RGB values are low, some black RGB values high, and some images have high blue or red values. Somehow I should find dynamic values for threshold from the images. Even can don't have the same light value for all part of an image.

Comment: Show another image that you think is hard to do.

Comment: I added another one but problem is that even a threshold work for these two, should be work on all of the images. Images quality is low and lights can be different. If the threshold is low, it will not work the same images, and if it is high, it will clear all images, I can not share them to show.

Comment: I usually try with RGB but I don't think that an HSV threshold exists for all too.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for these two images in Python/Opencv.

Input1:

[image]

Input2:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load images
img1 = cv2.imread('img1.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('img2.jpg')

# set black ranges
lower = (0,0,0)
upper = (50,30,50)

# threshold on black
result1 = cv2.inRange(img1, lower, upper)
result2 = cv2.inRange(img2, lower, upper)

# save output
cv2.imwrite('img1_thresh.jpg', result1)
cv2.imwrite('img2_thresh.jpg', result2)

# display results
cv2.imshow('img1_thresh',result1)
cv2.imshow('img2_thresh',result2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result1:

[image]

Result2:

[image]

Add a little morphology close to fill in the characters.

Comment: This not suitable. It does not work for nearly half of the image. I added two images more, and I am not looking for a couple of numbers. I already try with the tracking bar and I do not think that it is possible with const values. I need a method that finding dynamic values or some kind of filter that can be used with three channels or some image processing method that I do not know or should look at.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help further. I know of no universally appropriate solution.